# Identify this 3-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

This question is inspired by an old [UT prelim exam](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/academics/graduate/prelims/old_exams/2012_01_Topology-B.pdf) (question 2). Let me abbreviate the question here, getting right to the bonus which is all I need help with.

Let $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the standard unit sphere, and consider $S^2 \times S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3$. Let $f:S^2 \times S^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be the square of the Euclidean distance; $f(v,w)=d(v,w)^2$. Set $S=f^{-1}(1/2)$, so that $S$ is a compact $3$-dimensional submanifold of $S^2 \times S^2$. Can you identify $S$?

I think that projection (onto the first factor, say) induces a fiber bundle $p:S \to S^2$, and the preimage of a point is a circle, so I'm looking at an $S^1$-bundle over $S^2$ and I just need to know which one. From searching around I think something called the first Chern class would nail down which one, but it seems to me that some other invariant like (co)homology would work too.

Any thoughts or strategies are appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By working directly, one can see that $S$ is the sphere bundle of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb S^2$.

Let $x\in \mathbb S^2$. Then $(x, y) \in S$ if and only if $|x-y| = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$. All such $y$ (for each fixed $x$) corresponds to a circle on $\mathbb S^2$, and this circle lies in the plane perpendicular to the vector $x$. The total space of all these plane is obviously the tangent bundle of $\mathbb S^2$ and $S$ are those tangent vectors with length $\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: Interesting! I hadn't thought that the specific value would be so important. Can you say anything more about the space? These are supposed to be lens spaces right?

Comment: The specific value $c=\frac 12$ is not important (as long as it's in $(0,2)$).  Indeed $|x-y|  =c$ always corresponds to a circle lying inside the tangent plane (just with different radius). I guess it's a Lens space but I do not know which $p,q$ are. It's Chern class is $2$.

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Comment: @ArcticChar Could this be the lens space $L(2,1)$, perhaps? IIRC, the spaces $L(p,1)$ are circle bundles over $S^2$ with Chern class $p$. Then again, I don't *really* know what I'm talking about here ;)